# Key-only query doesn' work

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to query only the key from my entities but I only get a empty object back. All other queries work fine!

I do it the same way as in the docs. (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries)

```
const query = ds.createQuery()
    .select('__key__')
    .limit(1);

ds.runQuery(query)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: don't you need to specify the entity kind for the query?

Answer (score 0):

Dan is right -- you should specify a kind in the query. You'll also need to use the `KEY` symbol to access the key (see [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/0.8.0/datastore?method=KEY)).

For example:

```
const query = ds.createQuery('Task')
    .select('__key__')
    .limit(1);

ds.runQuery(query)
    .then((data) => {
      const entities = data[0];
      console.log(entities[0][ds.KEY]);
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```